# Updating data in SQLite (Node/Express)

Tags: javascript, sqlite, express

I'm trying to update a value in an SQLite database when a certain condition is met:

```
    if (req.headers['user-agent'].includes('HeadlessChrome') && (end - start <= 500))  {
        db.run("UPDATE tab SET var = ? WHERE var = ?", ['blah', '1234'],  (err) => {
            if(err) {
                return console.log(err.message); 
            }
        })
    }
```

However, nothing seems to be updating, even though I've confirmed that the if statement is entered - any ideas why? I have a feeling it's because I'm not waiting for db.run to finish executing. What would be the best way to go about this? I'm able to query data from the database okay, it's just updating isn't working.

Thanks!

Comment: Does the table tab exist and does it have a column named var with an entry 1234?

Comment: It does, I'm using a database browser to view it and print out the value. It prints out 1234 when db.all is run, but it doesn't update to 5678 beforehand.

Comment: What npm package are you using for the handling the db?

Comment: I'm using sqlite3.

Comment: can you try db.prepare instead of db.run? [this one?](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3)